# Require.js: is it possible for `define` to use node-style `next()` to delay returning a value?

Tags: requirejs

see codes below:

```
define(["dep1"], function (dep1, next) {

    // necessary works here so that `dep2` is ready
    // kind of circular dependency.
    someNecessaryWork();

    require(["dep2"], function (dep2) {
        // return value in node-style, using `next()`
        next(someValue);
    }
    // do not return value as normal, no `return someValue` here
}
```

Is `require.js` able to do this? For now I'm using functions to achieve this.

```
define(["dep1", "dep2Fn"], function (dep1, dep2Fn) { 
    someNecessaryWork();
    dep2Fn();
    return someValue;
});
```

but it feels not intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`define` does not allow you to set the return value of a module through a callback. What you show in your second snippet is how you do it. You just have to get used to it.